# Laravel Nova "relationResolver()" problem

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

This is the error I get when I want to use the Laravel Nova "nova-flexible-content" package, I don't know what the problem is and where I went wrong

```
Flexible::make('Content')
    ->addLayout('Simple content section', 'wysiwyg', [
        Text::make('Title'),
        Markdown::make('Content')
    ])
    ->addLayout('Video section', 'video', [
        Text::make('Title'),
        Image::make('Video Thumbnail', 'thumbnail'),
        Text::make('Video ID (YouTube)', 'video'),
        Text::make('Video Caption', 'caption')
    ])
```

->addLayout('Simple content section', 'wysiwyg', [......])

This is the error I get when I give the second parameter "wysiwyg" in the "addLayout" section

```
Call to undefined method App\Nova\Flexible\Layouts\SimpleWysiwygLayout::relationResolver()
```

I don't know where I made a mistake, I did the installation completely